# print gmplib's mpf_t number without exponent

Tags: c++, printing, gmp

Is there a way, using gmplib, to print an `mpf_t` number without the exponent?  I would rather not have to write a function that reads the exponent and moves the decimal manually, as that kind of seems like overkill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with gmplib, but does it support the [fixed](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/fixed/) formatting manipulator?

In standard C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   double d = 1.12345e6;

   cout << d << endl;
   cout << fixed << d << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

produces:

```
$ ./test
1.12345e+06
1123450.000000
```

You can play with the precision with `setprecision(n)` and width with `setw(n)` to further tweak the result.

Answer (score 1):

in fact, the GMPLib provide the way to print the mpf_t value well. See follows.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gmp.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    mpf_t f;
    mpf_init_set_str(f, "314.15926", 10);
    gmp_printf("%.5Ff\n", f);
    return 0;
}
```

if you run the script,the console will output:

```
314.15926
```

Here, the most important thing is about 5 in the GMT float format flag : **%.5Ff**,which means that it will output the float with 5 digitals